# How to select anonymous field?

Tags: go

From [GoQuery](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Document):

```
type Document struct {
    *Selection
    Url *url.URL
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

I want to get `*Selection` pointer from a `*Document` variable:

```
doc, e := goquery.NewDocument("http://www.gemalto.com/companyinfo/careers/")
var sel *goquery.Selection = doc // error!
sel = doc.(*goquery.Selection) // also error!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unqualified type name acts as the field name

```
var sel *goquery.Selection = doc.Selection
```

See the section on [Struct Types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) for details:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an
>   *anonymous field*, also called an *embedded* field or an embedding of the
>   type in the struct. An embedded type must be specified as a type name
>   `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may
>   not be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field
>   name.**